# LUIS - remove 'keyPhrase' from words in review endpoint utterances

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

When working in the LUIS gui, is there a way to remove 'keyPhrase' from suggested words?

[image: Here i would like to move the keyPhrase to *book* instead of *i'm*]

Here i would like to move the keyPhrase to *book* instead of *i'm*. But i can't remove the keyPhrase, nor can I add it to *book*.

UPDATE: adding screen shot of patterns:

[image]

Comment: Have you added it using Patterns feature?

Comment: Yes, i've added that exact Pattern (i'm looking for {keyPhrase})

Comment: Can you please send the snapshot of the pattern added. It looks like you have added: {keyPhrase} looking a book.

Comment: I notice now they are not exactly the same... but should be close enough.

Comment: Patterns feature doesn't work if they are close enough. They should be exactly the same pattern you are providing.

Comment: But my problem remains, I can't change the keyPhrase from "i'm" to "book" (or "a book")

Comment: You are trying label it in the review endpoint utterances. Instead of changing the label you have to delete the pattern in Pattern and provide a new pattern which should resolve the issue. Look into this https://blog.botframework.com/2018/06/07/improving-accuracy-in-luis-with-patterns/ for more information. If you are still unable to please add v-jyfani@microsoft.com as collaborator so that I can fix it for you.